# 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I want to create a tool layer in QGIS 2.4  that will select any vector features that intersect with that point. In my script I tried the following function:

```
def selectFeature(self, point, button):

       pntGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point)
       pntBuff = pntGeom.buffer( (self.canvas.mapUnitsPerPixel() * 2),0)
       rect = pntBuff.boundingBox()
       cLayer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
       selectList = []
       if cLayer:
               provider = cLayer.dataProvider()
               feat = QgsFeature()
               provider.select([],rect)
               while provider.nextFeature(feat):
                       if feat.geometry().intersects(pntGeom):
                               selectList.append(feat.id())
               cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
```

But I have the following error:

> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'select'
>   in line "provider.select([],rect)"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The follow code should replace everything in your `if` block:

```
if cLayer:
    for features in cLayer.getFeatures():
        if feat.geometry().intersects(pntGeom):
              selectList.append(feat.id())
     cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
```

The `select` method doesn't exist in any of the `2.0` version of QGIS. There is a `select` on the layer object however it is for visually selecting the objects on the screen which is not what you want here.

Pro tip:

Use the following code to limit your search area or else you will be looping every feature everytime regardless:

```
  if cLayer:
    rq = QgsFeatureRequest(rect)
    for features in cLayer.getFeatures(rq):
        if feat.geometry().intersects(pntGeom):
              selectList.append(feat.id())
     cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
```

This will create a `QgsFeatureRequest` which limits the search area to return features from via the passed in `QgsRectangle`

Comment: Thanks Nathan!!But if use this code don't solve the error, because it's in the previous line at cycle while or for.

Comment: See my updated code example

Comment: Hi Nathan!!!I used your updated code and I solved the problem. I made a change to putting in place of "for features" -> "for feat" and it works!!Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code, but it not work. It can't find selected feature.
So, I make an edit from your code. This is the edited code:

```
def selectFeature(self, point, button):
        pntGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point)
        pntBuff = pntGeom.buffer((self.canvas.mapUnitsPerPixel() * 2), 0)
        rect = pntBuff.boundingBox()

        cLayer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
        selectList = []
        if cLayer:
            rq = QgsFeatureRequest(rect)
            for feature in cLayer.getFeatures(rq):
                print feature
                if feature.geometry().intersects(rect):
                    selectList.append(feature.id())

            cLayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectList)
        else:
            print "No layer selected on TOC"

        print selectList
```

I am sorry I can't add this answer as comment, because my reputation are not enough. I hope this can help others.

Comment: it's OK to put his as an answer if it is the solution to your problem. Otherwise, please write this as an edit of your question